# Excel PowerQuery - extending #shared

Tags: excel, powerquery, extension-methods, get-transform

Is there a way to extend set of functions listed under #shared variable in Excel PowerQuery ?

I found a number of articles that describe how to write connectors for Power BI desktop and inject new code in #shared, and it seems that PowerQuery for Excel could not be extended injecting new authored functions in #shared.

There is PQ function Expression.Evaluate that allows loadind of new functions from external *.pq files into Excel PowerQuery, however I am looking for other way to inject reusable code directly in #shared.

Comment: There were plenty of people who really wanted that... some of whom have made PQ function repositories on GitGub. So I'm sure there is no way because if it was possible, it wouldn't have stayed a secret.

Comment: What did you end up doing? What I do is have an Excel Workbook that serves as my query function repository, and copy/paste function queries as I need them. It's cheesy but it's better for my needs to have queries contained within the workbooks that use them, rather than rely on file/web access to dependencies.

Comment: I ended up with "Expression.Evaluate". It is worth to use "Expression.Evaluate" and keep code outside of excel workbook for main reason that in case when amount of PQ code growth, Excel has to translate this code to base64 and apply security constrains on that code before PQ code is saved inside the workbook. However, if PQ code is outside in some *.pq file then Excel loads that code (using Expression.Evaluate) much faster and easier as compared to the same amount of code written in Excel PQ editor.